# how to delete all elements in a Lua table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

How do I delete all elements inside a Lua table?  I don't want to do:

```
t = {}
table.insert(t, 1)
t = {}  -- this assigns a new pointer to t
```

I want to retain the same pointer to t, but delete all elements within `t`.

I tried:

```
t = {}
table.insert(t, 1)
for i,v in ipairs(t) do table.remove(t, i) end
```

Is the above valid?  Or is something else needed?

Comment: I guess the situation is to empty a table in a function taking it as a parameter. Then the question is a good one, +1. I was at first confused about the word "pointer", which exists in c-code and shouldn't be mentioned in Lua-code. You mean "reference" or something.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
for k in pairs (t) do
    t [k] = nil
end
```

Will also work - you may have difficulty with ipairs if the table isn't used as an array throughout.

Answer (score 28):

Table elements insert and remove
performance compare

The Table size count 10000000

[1] while and rawset

```
while #t ~= 0 do rawset(t, #t, nil) end
```

spent time = 0.677220

[2] next and rawset

```
for k in next, t do rawset(t, k, nil) end
```

spent time = 0.344533

[3] ipairs and rawset

```
for i, v in ipairs(t) do t[i] = nil end
```

spent time = 0.012450

[4] for, rawset

```
count = #t
for i=0, count do t[i]=nil end
```

spent time = 0.009308

Table elemnets insert

[1] table insert function

```
for i=0, 10000000 do    table.insert(t, i, i) end
```

spent time = 1.0590489

[2] use #t

```
for i=0, 10000000 do    t[#t+1] = i end
```

spent time = 0.703731

[3] for, rawset

```
for i=0, 10000000 do rawset(t, i, i) end
```

spent time = 0.100010

result.

> Fastest remove : 4
>
> Fastest insert : 3

Comment: This is a thorough and effective answer.

Answer (score 15):

easiest and most performant:

```
for k, _ in pairs(tab) do tab[k] = nil end
```

What you suggest isn't usable: `table.remove` shifts the remaining elements to close the hole, and thus messes up the table traversal. See the description for [the next function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next) for more info

Answer (score 4):

For a faster version that ignores the `__pairs` metamethod:

```lua
local next = next
local k = next(tab)
while k ~= nil do
  tab[k] = nil
  k = next(tab, k)
end
```

EDIT: As @siffiejoe mentions in the comments, this can be simplified back into a for loop by replacing the `pairs` call with its default return value for tables: the `next` method and the table itself. Additionally, to avoid all metamethods, use the `rawset` method for table index assignment:

```lua
for k in next, tab do rawset(tab, k, nil) end
```

Comment: Or just `for k in next,tab do tab[k] = nil end`

Comment: According to https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf (a Lua optimization guide), this method is surprisingly terrible. The problem is that setting an element to nil _typically does not delete it from the table_ until the next resize. The implementation of next has to search through all the nils before it returns, making this a surprise O(n^2).

Comment: @AHelps Thanks for pointing that out! My longer `while` version doesn't suffer from this because `next` is called with a previous index. @siffiejoe's version is missing that part, so it does the slow version. I'll make an explanatory edit to the answer.

Comment: @AHelps actually, I take that back: the "generic `for` loop" construct automatically takes the return value of the iterator function as the second parameter to the function in the next iteration. So first iteration is `k = next(tab, nil)`, but the next iteration is `k = next(tab, k)`, which avoids the full traversal.

Answer (score 1):

`#table` is the table size and so if `t = {1,2,3}` then `#t = 3`

So you can use this code to remove the elements

`while #t ~= 0 do rawset(t, #t, nil) end`

You will go through the table and remove each element and you get an empty table in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable to anything else and then back to a table, so then it is empty.

```
t = {1,2,3}
print(t[1])      -- 1
t = "Hello World"
print(t)          -- Hello World
t = {}
print(t[1])       -- nil
```