# How to wipe or reset a table in Lua

Tags: lua, reset, lua-table

How would I go about completely wiping or resetting a table in Lua. I want to make it into a blank table in the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete all elements in a Lua table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880368/how-to-delete-all-elements-in-a-lua-table)

Answer (score 9):

You iterate over the keys and make them nil.

```
for k,v in pairs(t) do
  t[k] = nil
end
```

If it's an array then remove values with table.remove()

Comment: If using remove, start removing *at the end* of the array, otherwise it will take a long time, as all elements after the created hole need to be moved. The approach using `pairs` is much faster.

Comment: Please note that, while this will work for most of the tables, it is possible to craft a table which would not be cleaned in this way, using metatables.

Answer (score 3):

What about this way?

```
t = {..some non-empty table..}
...some code...
t={}
```

Comment: This replaces one table with another, not wipes its contents. (That being said, this is often the preferred way.)

Comment: If no more vars linked to target's table - then gc will delete it from memory and will create a new table with a new physical address.
Else nulling every element useing loop is the best thing.

Answer (score 0):

this will create a new table 't' with a new pointer and delete old values:

```
t = {1, 2, 3}
t = {}
collectgarbage()
```

this one will delete all values of the table and you will end up with no table:

```
t = {1, 2, 3}
t = nil
collectgarbage()
```